# Trying to send to hellog world over arduino serial

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: Tried to deleting ros_lib and recompiling getting same results. Note: I am using a MacPro running ubuntu 13.04 the USB is 3.0.

Trying to send to hello world over arduino serial get the following error:  Running Hydro

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1390939261.052431] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1390939261.059605] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud




[ERROR] [WallTime: 1390939353.203464] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123586/trying-to-send-to-hellog-world-over-arduino-serial/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try remaking your ros_lib.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2